# api plateform, fix out iri converter

Tags: php, identifier, api-platform.com, iri

I'm looking for approach to find out retrieve an resource not depending on it's id but something like `username, GET /api/user/{username}`.

So I did something like this:

```
/**
* @ApiRessource({
*     itemOperations={
*         "get"={
*             "normalization_context"={"groups"={"user:read"}},
*             "path"="/user/{username}", "read"=false,
*             "controller"=ApiUser::class,
*             "openapi_context"={
*                  "summary" = "Récupérer un freehelper en particulier par son nom"
*              },
*          },
})
*/
class User{
{
    /**
     * @Groups({"user:read"})
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=false)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Groups({"user:read"})
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=56, unique=true)
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     */
    private $username;
....
}
```

and then I write and `dataproider` as described [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/identifiers/), so I got this error

```
"detail": "Unable to generate an IRI for \"App\\Entity\\User\".",
```

Can you help me understanding how to do that?

Comment: Do you have some `RuntimeException` at logs? Will it change if add `@var string` to phpdoc?

Comment: @shvv I slightly changed the ressource add ResourceController and log says 
**Some mandatory parameters are missing (\"username\") to generate a URL for route \"get_user\"**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in ApiUser controller like that:

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/{username}", name="api_user_username", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function getByUsername($username)
{
    $event = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)
                ->findOneBy(["username" => $username));

    return $this->httpKernel
                ->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST, false);
}
```

Comment: thank your for quick reply @Khaled,
I don't understand how and when this method getByUsername will be call then, as described on the docs, __invoke should take place and I implemented this with description route, would explain more this, thank you.

Comment: Symfony's controllers are not recommended. Beside, note that a controller is ONLY called on the request it is declared, never when fetching entities relation for example.

Comment: @rugolinifr, yeah you're right, according to you, how should retrieve an item by different property not id? like /user/{property_different_id} ? thank you, I'm bit confused.

Comment: I think the only error you've done so far is to declare a new path to your _get_ item operation. You should remove it and keep the openApi view showing **/api/users/{id}**. The _{id}_ word does not mean "private $id;" but "identifier". Since you have followed the documentation page to change you identifier, it is ok. Do we agree that your **ItemDataProviderInterface::getItem()**  implementation is something like `return $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['username' => $id]);` ? If yes, then your user entities should be serialized/deserialized with URLs like **/api/users/foo**.